# What are the numbers in the upper right corner?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2, call-of-duty-black-ops

In Call-Of-Duty Black-OPS and Modern-Warfare-2, there are 2 series of numbers in the upper right corner.

I thought they could be be an IP but one of these numbers is 0 in MW2.

I thought they could be the version, but the first number is 50 in BO.

I don't know if these numbers exist in other version of COD.

What do they mean?

Comment: IP addresses can include 0.

Comment: I don't own either game, but could it be a version number? Does the number appear on the title screen, or while playing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the current production version of the each game.  It started to display the current version number with Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare.

Answer (score 1):

On Black Ops, this begins at 50.0.0.0, but then when it connects to the Playstation Network to go into multiplayer, this updates to the newest version (currently 53.x.x.x). These updates seem to be downloaded quietly and quickly.

Answer (score -3):

Well I am not positive but I think it means the number of servers being used at once. But again I am not positive this is the right answer. ;-)